# How do I fix the error: "A RenderFlex overflowed by 71 pixels on the right." and make the columns fit the screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Currently in my flutter app I get this error after adding a new column in the DataTable: "A RenderFlex overflowed by 71 pixels on the right."
How can I correct this so that the columns adapt to the screen size?

```
 // For CircularProgressIndicator.
  bool visible = false;
  String? dropdownValue = 'Hoy';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        leading: BackButton(
          color: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage(0, 0)));
          },
        ),
        title: new Text("Planilla de horarios"),
      ),
      body: (!visible)
          ? Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                        FutureBuilder<String>(
                            future: globals.SharedPreferencesHelper
                                .getDataFilterDebt(),
                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                return Expanded(
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Expanded(
                                        flex: 2,
                                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                          value: dropdownValue,
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                                          iconSize: 24,
                                          iconEnabledColor: Colors.white,
                                          elevation: 16,
                                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                          underline: Container(
                                            height: 0,
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                          ),
                                          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              dropdownValue = newValue;
                                            });
                                          },
                                          items: <String>['Hoy', 'Mañana']
                                              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                                                  (String value) {
                                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                              value: value,
                                              child: Text(value),
                                            );
                                          }).toList(),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                        margin:
                                            const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                        child: new Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              FlatButton(
                                                child: Text("Buscar"),
                                                color: Color(0xFF1F1F1F),
                                                textColor: Colors.white,
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    left: 2,
                                                    right: 2,
                                                    top: 2,
                                                    bottom: 2),
                                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius.circular(
                                                            5)),
                                                onPressed: () {
                                                  obtenerDetallesTecnicasImplantes(
                                                      dropdownValue.toString());

                                                  setState(() {});
                                                },
                                              ),
                                            ]),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                );
                              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                return Image.asset("images/fundo_login.jpg");
                              } else {
                                return Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 18),
                                  child: Row(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Visibility(
                                          child: Container(
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 17.5),
                                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                          valueColor:
                                              AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                                  Colors.black),
                                        ),
                                        height: 20,
                                        width: 20,
                                      )),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                );
                              }
                            }),
                      ]),
                    ),
                    DataTable(
                      columns: [
                        DataColumn(label: Text('Hora')),
                        DataColumn(label: Text('Sector')),
                        DataColumn(label: Text('Agente')),
                        DataColumn(label: Text('Agente de cobertura')),
                      ],
                      rows:
                          scheduleList // Loops through dataColumnText, each iteration assigning the value to element
                              .map(
                                ((element) => DataRow(
                                      cells: <DataCell>[
                                        DataCell(Text(element![
                                            "ingreso"])), //Extracting from Map element the value
                                        DataCell(
                                            Text(element["sector_nombre"])),
                                        DataCell(Text(element["apellidos"] +
                                            " " +
                                            element["nombres"])),
                                       DataCell(Text(element["agente_cobertura_det"])),
                                      ],
                                    )),
                              )
                              .toList(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          : pageLoadingView(),
    );
  }

  Widget pageLoadingView() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 300),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Visibility(
              visible: visible,
              child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.black),
                  ))),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Color hexToColor(String code) {
    return new Color(int.parse(code.substring(1, 7), radix: 16) + 0xFF000000);
  }
}
```

[image]

Currently in my flutter app I get this error after adding a new column in the DataTable.................

Comment: Make sure that if you have a flex widget inside an other (Column inside Row or vice versa), you should wrap it with Expanded or Flexible. Also, consider to separate your code to more simple and smaller widgets in order to improve readability.

Comment: Could you show me this solution in my code please? I'm a noob